# Construct the truth table?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

Any body help me .. How to solve this?

> (i)   $(p\land q)\to (p \leftrightarrow (q \lor r))$
>
> (ii)  $(p \leftrightarrow q) \leftrightarrow ((p\land q) \lor (\neg q \land \neg p))$
>
> (iii) $(p \lor q) \leftrightarrow \neg(\neg p \land \neg q)$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Please, take a moment to write down what you have already done so we can help you.

Comment: @5xum I'm new to this site and also this like maths... Please send me solved links please........

Comment: I believe you don't quite understand how this site works. It's not about "I send you problems, you solve them." You are the one solving the problems, we are the ones that help you. For that, we want to see some effort shown.

Comment: @5xum not like that.. I don't have books. I search on google no Result. Okay fine I Try to solve it..Thank You..

Comment: But if you do not have textbook or lecture notes, were do come from the problem ? See in Wiki : [Truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) with the truth-functional definition of the *connectives* and application to the formula : $(p → q) \leftrightarrow (¬p ∨ q)$.

Comment: See also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/provide-truth-table)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for your helping..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will be helpful:
i.
$((p\wedge q)\to(p\equiv(q\vee r)))$
$a:p\wedge q$
$b:q\vee r$
$c:p\equiv b$
$d:a\to c$
$\begin{matrix}
p&q&r&a&b&c&d\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&0&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&1&0&1&0&1\\
1&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
1&0&1&0&1&1&1\\
1&1&0&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
 \end{matrix}$

Answer (score 1):

Following Mauro's suggestion, I'll give you a general algorithm using truth-tables, focusing on (i).

Let n be the number of distinct propositional letters ocurring in the formula (e.g. for (i) you'll have |{p, q, r}| = 3). Generate a [truth-table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) of 2<sup>n</sup> rows. In the case of (i), for example, n = 2<sup>3</sup> = 8. In order to prove (i), consider those rows out of the 8 that make (p ∧ q) true. Now check, do those rows make (p ↔ (q ∨ r)) true? To answer those two questions, you need to look at the [truth-conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Truth_table_for_all_binary_logical_operators) for the connectives ∧, →, ↔, ∨. Each row of the truth-table assigns a value (⊤ or ⊥) to p, q, and r. The truth-conditions allow you to evaluate the truth-value of compound expressions like (p ∧ q) using nothing more than the truth-values of p and q.

Once you know how to calculate the truth-value of compounds using the truth-values of the atoms, you can answer all three of your questions. When you do, show your work if you need guidance.